# My SwipeRefreshLayout do not stop showing after data has been loaded

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I want to stop refreshing the recyclerview after the data is loaded but it keeps showing. I want the SwipeRefreshLayout to disappear after the the data of the recyclerview is fully loaded

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_likely_problems"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/zerodimen"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/zerodimen"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/zerodimen"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/zerodimen"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.system2.tranxav.LIkelyProblemsActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/background" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/likelyProblemSwipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/likelyProblemRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

LikelyProblemActivity

```
public class LIkelyProblemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_problem);

       SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.likelyProblemSwipeToRefresh);

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (swipeRefreshLayout !=null){
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            }
            loadLikelyProblems();

        }
    }, 3000);
 public void loadLikelyProblems(){


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LIKELY_PROBLEM_URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("info", response);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i=0; i<=jsonArray.length()-1; i++){
                    JSONObject likelyProblemJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    likelyProblem = likelyProblemJson.getString("problems");
                    LikelyProblems likelyProblems = new LikelyProblems(likelyProblem);
                    mlikelyProblems.add(likelyProblems);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(likelyProblemAdapter);
                }
                likelyProblemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}
}
```

I have browse through the code but the I cant figure out what the problem really is. need some help

Answer (score 2):

Use **`swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);`** inside **`onResponse(String response)`** method

> [**`setRefreshing(boolean refreshing)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean))

- Notify the widget that refresh state has changed.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LIKELY_PROBLEM_URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("info", response);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i=0; i<=jsonArray.length()-1; i++){
                    JSONObject likelyProblemJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    likelyProblem = likelyProblemJson.getString("problems");
                    LikelyProblems likelyProblems = new LikelyProblems(likelyProblem);
                    mlikelyProblems.add(likelyProblems);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(likelyProblemAdapter);
                }
                likelyProblemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               loadLikelyProblems();
            }
        });
```

Comment: the swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); is inside the response but is not working for me

Comment: Remove `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` from `onRefresh()` method

Comment: I have removed it from the onRefresh() method but is still the same issue. When I swipe it down the swipeRefreshLayout displays and does not go away

Comment: @user2940930 make sure you have not  added `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` after calling your `loadLikelyProblems()` method please check once in your activity

Comment: I just updated my activity with the SwipeRefresh code please check it

Comment: I have done that and still the same problem. I dont have any other place i set swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);. I dont know what is really wrong

Answer (score 0):

Put `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` out of `try-catch` blocks and duplicate that into the `onErrorResponse()` method.

Comment: Call `loadLikelyProblems` from `onRefresh` method and remove `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` from that. Remove `swipeRefreshLayout.postDelayed`  for test and if it works, keep that.